# GCE - Windows Remote Desktop - No Remote Desktop License Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, google-compute-engine

Having Windows Server instance in Google Compute Engine. Used to connect using Remote desktop and it was working fine. for Last few days cant able to do Remote Desktop via Mac and Windows machine. 
It says :

> The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote
>   Desktop License Servers available to provide a license.

Completly server was locked out, as in Cloud it is not possible anyway to directly access the server. How to get it resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is possible for an administrator to connect using the `mstsc.exe /admin` switch.

Then the administrator can install the Remote Desktop Licensing role feature, and configure the server to use itself as the license server using gpedit.msc.

Computer > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Licensing

[image: RD License Server]